# Why does my POST request to Google's geolocation api return a bad request 400 error?

Tags: http, google-api

I'm trying to add geolocation to an application via Google's geolocation API. However, when testing the http call in hurl.it I get a 400 bad request error. Here's my http request: `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MYKEY`

See the attached screenshot -> [Hurl.it Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1N5N.png)

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en_US) is very simple so I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had been on a public university's internet and apparently they blocked my http call. Everything works now.